# Android - styling custom Dialog

Tags: android

I have a custom dialog in an xml layout.
How can I style it so it:

1. doesn't have a title
2. in other cases when I do want a title, change the color of the title divider line
3. has completely square edges instead of those slightly rounded corners that Android dialogs have by default

Comment: first you need a custom view. Inflate a custom layout and set it to dialog. Style individual views the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android customising style [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

There is style folder inside res folder. Please take look over it. it basically xml file which has resource tags where you can configure you custom styling. And refer the same styling from style attribute in xml.

Comment: Yes, so simple, just add style="" to the LinearLayout in the dialog layout. Don't know why I thought styles should be set in the AndroidManifest

Comment: @PFort you can set style to individual views as well

Comment: @sush there is not styles folder. its styles.xml

Comment: I think he meant in the SDK folder, I see all kinds of styles there that give me an idea on what can be changed